# Propositional calculus.

Tags: logic

A, a proposition in Propositional calculus is called "Monotonic" if when there is an assigning M s.t $$M\models{A}$$ any other  assigning $M'$ that similar to $M$ on the True values  but may change False values to True maintains  $$M'\models{A}$$
Prove: A is logically equivalent to a proposition that built out of the connectives $\{\lor, \land\}$ if and only if A is Monotonic, not a contradiction and not a tautology.

I was able to prove one direction (with induction on the structure of A) but i'm having difficulties to prove the other direction (assuming A is monotonic...).

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be the set of variables in the formula $A$, and consider the set $\Gamma$ of all of its subsets $X\subseteq V$ which makes $A$ valid w.r.t. the assigning $M_X:=\big\{(x\mapsto$"true"$)$ iff $x\in X\big\}$:
$$\Gamma\ :=\ \{X\subseteq V\ \mid\ M_X\models A\}$$

(Alternatively, you can keep only the *minimal* nonempty elements of $\Gamma$, w.r.t. inclusion.)

Then let $B:=\displaystyle\bigvee_{X\in\Gamma}\left(\bigwedge_{x\in X}x\right)$, and verify that $A\Leftrightarrow B$, using the condition on $A$ for $(M\models B)\Rightarrow (M\models A)$.

Comment: cool thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Do you have an advice how could i figure it out myself? thinking about that direction....

Comment: Since each formula is equivalent to its disjunctive normal form, we can assume that $A$ is already in disj.normal form, i.e. it is a disjunction of 'clauses'. Now negation should not be included, so each clause is of the form $\land_{x\in X}x$ for a set $X$ of plain (not negated) variables. Then collect, which clauses could be included in $A$...